# Unselect a listbox item if it contains a specific character (don't allow its selection)

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox1 with a list of items. If a user has to select an item with a single mouse click and if that selected list item has an equal sign in it, it must immediately display a message stating this and deselect the item.

I have looked at various solutions all of which does not work as I want it to:-

Below is my code which works ummmm most of the time but not when two or more items have already been previously selected. I need a always will work solution.

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseClick

    For I = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
        If Not ListBox1.Items(I).ToString.Contains("=") Then
            ListBox1.SetSelected(I, False)
            '  MsgBox("Please only select items that have = in description ! ! ! Edit item if you want to include . . .", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    Next
    ListBox1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better using [SelectedIndexChangedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    With CType(sender, ListBox)

        For i As Integer = .SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

            If Not IsNothing(.SelectedItems(i)) AndAlso Not .SelectedItems(i).ToString.Contains("=") Then
                MsgBox("Invalid selection.")
                .SelectedItems.Remove(.SelectedItems(i))
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work if another item is selected before the one with the = in it. Also the logic is incorrect the line of code; it should be :-If Not IsNothing(.SelectedItem) AndAlso Not .SelectedItem.ToString.Contains("=") Then

Comment: @BASitBulbulia  I have changed the logic according to your comment but note that your question is unselect a listbox item if it contains a specific character (equal sign?). If I understand correctly you also use a ListBox with multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this problem is to get - in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event - the indices of the invalid selections if any to deselect them and show the message. Handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event in particular is to make it work with the mouse and keyboard inputs.

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    With ListBox1
        Dim invalidSel = .SelectedIndices.Cast(Of Integer).
            Where(Function(i) Not .GetItemText(.Items(i)).Contains("="))

        If invalidSel.Any() Then
            RemoveHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged,
                AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

            For Each i In invalidSel
                .SetSelected(i, False)
            Next
            MessageBox.Show("Please....")

            AddHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged,
                AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Note, removing then adding the handler again is to avoid showing the message box repeatedly in the multi-selection modes. Without it, the event fires for each `.SetSelected(i, False)` call.